# Is there a full map of the Redwall world?

Tags: redwall, map

Is there any map which fully covers the world of Redwall? Each book seems to only have a small chunk of it. (And they don't always seem to match up.)

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive given that the map below is printed in an authorised work. Are you anticipating that there will be any additional detail that can be added before you consider an acceptance?

Comment: @Valorum - I'll accept. I was just hoping for a map which covers all the books.

Comment: I'll keep on the lookout for an update but I think this is the best you're gonna get unless they do literally do a "new and improved edition" version.

Comment: @Valorum - I would rather a complete map than an authoritative map. (Which really doesn't seem that likely, with Brian Jacques being dead and all.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the map from "[Redwall Map & Riddler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0399232486)", described thusly

> Escape into the land of Redwall with this beautifully illustrated
>   full-color fold-out map. Explore the treacherous terrain, legendary
>   landmarks, and wondrous sites which Brian Jacques has made famous in
>   his Redwall tales.

[image: map of "Redwall Country and beyond"]

Please note that every source I've read [repeatedly mentions that this map has glaring inconsistencies](https://www.reddit.com/r/eulalia/comments/2686he/how_accurate_is_this_map_of_the_world_of_redwall/) but that, in-universe, this could be excused by the inability of the main characters to create accurate maps.

Comment: That map doesn't cover the last twelve books. (But +1 because I hadn't known it existed.)

Comment: This makes me want to reread some of Redwall!

Comment: yeah the author fiddles with the map himself and it takes a day in one book and a week in another to get to similar places